# is there a way to convert an rdd to df ignoring lines that don't fit the schema?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a large file of jsons (can't post any, sorry for that) varying in number of keys and datatype of values of identical keys as well - is there a way to put all the lines that follow a schema (hard-coded or inferred) into a dataframe and leave all the lines that don't fit the schema in an rdd?
Eventually, I would like to iterate through such a process and get a couple of df's each one with its own schema at the end.

here is a close to reality example:

```
a = [['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']]*22
b =[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']]*22
rdd_1 = sc.parallelize(a+b)

rdd_1.toDF().show(30)
```

this fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have 
expected number of values required by the schema. 3 fields are 
required while 4 values are provided.
```

In this specific case I could form a function that adds null in case of less than max fields, but I'm after a more generic try and except method that could tackle nested data with unpredictable schema changes.

any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you have JSON as input, json reader can gracefully handle malformed data, as long as you provide schema. Same apply to dict objects which can be parsed by json parser.

Comment: but I have more than 1 schema, look at my example, what would a json parser solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with **rdd** you could load this file to a **dataframe** (if it's present in any stable storage like HDFS/Amazone S3 of course), with mode = PERMISSIVE. First prepare a generic schema of yours to work with. The code is the following.

```
df = sqlContext.read.schema(<your-schema>).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json(<file-path>)
```

The spark documentation says -

**PERMISSIVE** : sets other fields to null when it meets a corrupted record and puts the malformed string into a new field configured by spark.sql.columnNameOfCorruptRecord. When a schema is set by user, it sets null for extra fields.

**DROPMALFORMED** : ignores the whole corrupted records.

**FAILFAST**: throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

Find details in this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13764).

Hope, this helps.